# Wilcox.test for testing count based data in R studio large W

Tags: r, t-test

I'm doing a textmining project about a videogame review dataset. I divided de reviews into a positive (reviewgrade > 8) and negative (reviewgrade < 3) and want to draw conclusions based on the frequency of different grading factors mentioned in the text. I now have a dataframe with counts of certain categories mentioned per review.

```
0    13249
1     1565
2      292
3       65
4       19
5        6
6        4
7        3
8        2
9        1
Name: positive: gameplay, dtype: int64
```

```
0    5043
1     348
2      66
3      18
4       8
5       3
Name: negative: gameplay, dtype: int64
```

For example this are the distributions of the amount of reviews which have a certain amount of mentions of gameplay related words. There are for example 1565 reviews with precisely 1 mention of a word related to the category gameplay.
Now I want to use this data to determine if on average gameplay gets mentioned more in negative context than in positive or vice versa.
Because the data is not normal distributed, I assumed a t-test is not appropriate, and found online that a Mann–Whitney U test might be suitable.

```
> wilcox.test(positive$gameplay, negative$gameplay, alternative = "two.sided", conf.int = TRUE)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  positive$gameplay and negative$gameplay
W = 43702925, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.963844e-05 4.797412e-05
sample estimates:
difference in location 
          4.995671e-05
```

I do however get a very high W value, which doesn't seem to be correct. 
Is this not the appropriate test, or am I interpreting this wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438052/wilcox-test-for-testing-count-based-data-in-r-studio-large-w

Comment: @blaurens if a post is off topic on one site, *don't* post a second copy there. Flag the original to migrate. That way when the original migrates anyway, we don't end up with identical copies of the same question.